# Airflow : Not receiving an Error message in Email, whenever the DAG/TASK is failed with on_failure_callback

Tags: airflow

Airflow version 1.10.3

Below is the module code that is been called by `on_failure_callback`

I have used `reason = context.get("exception")`, But I get an error as None in the email when the job is failed instead of getting an error message

Output in the email:
`Reason for Failure: None`

**alert_email.py**

```py
from airflow.utils.email import send_email
from airflow.models import Variable

def failure_alert(context, config=None):
    config = {} if config is None else config
    email          = config.get('email_id')
    task_id        = context.get('task_instance').task_id
    dag_id         = context.get("dag").dag_id
    execution_time = context.get("execution_date")
    reason         = context.get("exception")

    dag_failure_html_body = f"""<html>
    <header><title>The below DAG has failed!</title></header>
    <body>
    <b>DAG Name</b>: {dag_id}<br/>
    <b>Task Id</b>: {task_id}<br/>
    <b>Execution Time (UTC)</b>: {execution_time}<br/>
    <b>Reason for Failure</b>: {reason}<br/>
    </body>
    </html>
    """

    try:
        send_email(
            to=email,
            subject=f"Airflow alert: <DagInstance: {dag_id} - {execution_time} [failed]",
            html_content=dag_failure_html_body,
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'Error in sending email to address {email}: {e}', exc_info=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the version Airflow 1.10.3. We will be upgrading into Airflow 1.10.10